# fatal: Needed a single revision(gitlab runner error)

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

When adding a submodule  to my Gitlab repo, I install the main branch:

git submodule add -b main ../../some-project/my-repo.git

After that I use the gitlab runner with variables:

GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: normal

GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS: "--remote --merge"

Everything works fine, but when you change the submodule branch in .gitmodules to another one, let's say "feature" (changed both manually in the file and with the command git submodule set-branch -b feature my-repo), then the pipeline drops with this: fatal: Needed a single revision

Unable to find current origin/feature revision in submodule path 'my-repo'

Locally, the command "git submodule update --init --remote --merge my-repo" works fine, updating the submodule to the latest commit in the "feature" branch

Comment: Hi, How to get "GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS" or where is located? I have face the "fatal: needed a single revision gitlab" error.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution:

GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS: "--remote --checkout --no-single-branch"

Comment: Hi, How to get "GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS" or where is located? I have face the "fatal: needed a single revision gitlab" error.

Comment: My GitLab runner did not like the --no-single-branch flag.